getting an error window is not defined when using react-draft-wysiwyg in next js client side component
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";

I have done these code please help me writing the code
<Editor
    editorState={formData.body}
    onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
    wrapperClassName="border rounded-md"
    editorClassName="p-4"/>


##Dynamically import the editor to avoid SSR issues
const Editor = dynamic(
() => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
{ ssr: false }
);
